# Nginx allow insecure contents on page

Tags: grails, nginx

My application is being served over Nginx and I have configured the SSL.
All contents are being served on HTTP. There is a functionality where a user can link their video and application suppose to show that video.

But every time when I access that page, Nginx did not allow to show that HTTP video's on the page saying insecure content.

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: Nginx has nothing to do with it. It's your browser policy and all you could do is to use https for all assets on secure page.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is complaining because your are loading images or javascript from "http://" wich is not allowed from https-contexts. Check your source code whether you have an absolute URL pointing to "http://". If so, you need to search an HTTPS-alternative of this URL. If you have luck you can just replace http with https.

Comment: Here the user can add a link to their video or audio it means I have no control over it :(.

Comment: You could replace http with https using regex on user generated content.